# ng-select is not sending the id of the field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, I have an ng-select box that I can select countries from, the ng-select option is working fine, and when I submit the option that I selected it submits the id, however, when I bind data to the ng-select and submit the data that was already showing it submits the name instead of the id, I would like to submit the id instead, I have tried the below but seems that something is wrong.
I understand this is very basic but I've been trying the past 3 hours, appreciate your assistance.

company.component.ts

```
Country: new FormGroup({
    Id: new FormControl('')
  }),

getCountries(){
this.restService.GetAllCountries().subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.countries = res.data.lookups
  })
}

getCompany(){
  this.restService.getCompanyData(this.role).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.countryLookupId = this.company.country.name_FL;
  //this returns with a string
})
}
```

company.component.html

```
<ng-select *ngIf="show" formControlName="Id" [(ngModel)]="countryLookupId" class="width">
<ng-option [value]="country.id" *ngFor="let country of countries">{{ country.name_FL }} 
</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Can you create StackBlitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there's a `countryLookupId: string;` property that you haven't included?

The problem is that `this.countryLookupId` should be the country id, not the country name. It should match the option value, not the display text.

```
this.countryLookupId = this.company.country.id;
```

Edit:

And you're not setting the options correctly:

ng-select expects you to provide an array of items:

```
items: [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  // some code to get countries
  //...


  this.items = countries.map.(x => ({ id: country.id, name: country.name_FL }));
}
```

```
<ng-select [items]="items"></ng-select>
```

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Edit:

This is what I think your html should look like, assuming that you are now directly using the country array:

```
<ng-select *ngIf="countries" [(ngModel)]="countryLookupId" class="width" 
 [items]="countries" bindValue="id" bindLabel="name_FL">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: I have changed it however it is now showing the id and sending the id, so how to show the name_FL but send the id ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Reading the ng-select docs, you are expected to provide an array of items rather than provide option html.

Comment: getCountries(){
    this.restService.GetAllCountries().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.countries = res.data.lookups
      
      this.items = this.countries.map(x => x);
      console.log(this.items)
    })
  }

<ng-select [items]="items"></ng-select>

Comment: You didn't follow my suggestion. items is expected to be an array of `{ id, name }` objects. You can also set bindValue and bindLabel on ng-select if you want to just bind to your array of countries. Read the docs.

Comment: I apoligize, I have updated it now to the following: 
this.items = this.countries.map(x => ({ id: x.id, name: x.name_FL }));

Comment: Yes that is working, but still the ngModel is not coming up with the country name when using this.countryLookupId = this.company.country.id;

this is my updated HTML:

<ng-select [items]="items"
            bindLabel="name"
            bindValue="id"
            formControlName="Id"
            [(ngModel)]="countryLookupId">
        </ng-select>

Comment: I've just reaslised you're using both formControlName and ngModel. You should use only one of them. Use formControlName if binding to a form, and ngModel if binding to a single value. Here you should be using ngModel.

Comment: Just remove formControlName="", leave [(ngModel)]

Comment: When I used this approach it came up with an error ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'Country

Comment: I've edited my answer to have a guess at what I think your html should look like

Comment: No problem. It's worth taking a second to learn about what's going on here. [(ngModel)] is doing a lot of work for you here. Everything else is basic javascript or specific to the ng-select library.